# Unable to locate sound file (.ogg)

Tags: audio, jmonkeyengine

I have a method called setSound() which is setting up a queue and adding a track to it and then playing it. I call the method in simpleInitGame(). However no sound plays and the console in eclipse says:

```
Mar 13, 2012 10:15:55 PM com.jmex.audio.openal.OpenALSystem setupSourcePool
INFO: max source channels: 32
Mar 13, 2012 10:15:55 PM com.jme.util.resource.ResourceLocatorTool locateResource
WARNING: Unable to locate: src/com/preston/sounds/background.ogg
Mar 13, 2012 10:15:55 PM com.jmex.audio.openal.OpenALSystem createAudioTrack
WARNING: Could not locate audio file: src/com/preston/sounds/background.ogg
```

Here is the method:

```
protected void setSound()
    {
        audio = AudioSystem.getSystem();
        sound1 = audio.createAudioTrack("src/com/preston/sounds/background.ogg", false);
        queue = AudioSystem.getSystem().getMusicQueue();
        queue.setCrossfadeinTime(0);
        queue.setRepeatType(RepeatType.ONE);
        queue.addTrack(sound1);
queue.play();

    }
```

I don't think it's the directory as my textures are in the same directory (except instead of preston/sounds its preston/textures).

Comment: are the permissions on the directory/file set up properly for eclipse to be able to access the contents of the directory/file?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, if eclipse can access the textures for my shapes (e.g. skybox) fine does that mean it's fine for audio too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is most probably a problem with your relative path. The default directory of the ResourceLocatorTool in jMonkeyEngine is not the root of your project. Try to open it with an absolute path and see if it works.

Also, the location of your file is not a wise choice. The src folder is intended for java source files, not resources. You should put them in assets/Sounds. See [jME best practices](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3aintermediate%3abest_practices#multi-media_asset_pipeline)

Comment: By the way it seems that you're using a deprecated audio module for jME, consider using http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:audio_environment_presets

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can omit the "src/" prefix. The Eclipse compiler will compile all java files into class files and in addition copy the resources from your sources to "bin/".
I think JME then uses ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...) to load assets from the classpath. So, try removing "src/".